# how can i check that string variable represent a point struct?

Tags: c#, point, formatexception

`Point.Parse("SomeText");`

how can i check if the given string represent a point ?

Parse Method Documentation is [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.parse.aspx)

Comment: Check if the parse succeeds? You should proabbly narrow this question down and show us some of your code, like for example the actual `Parse` method.

Comment: Parse method throw FormatException if the string is not like "55,22" @aevitas

Comment: Can you show us the code for `Parse`?

Comment: Oops i'm sorry for being ambiguous i use Microsoft dot net method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.parse.aspx

Comment: Alright, and why do you want to avoid try/catch?

Comment: i think it will slow down application performance specially if i used it frequently in a loop for example

Comment: It won't, and by the looks of it it's the only way you can actually tell whether or not a `Parse` succeeded. You could always just set a `success` value to false in the `catch` clause and rethrow or ignore the exception to determine whether or not you have a valid point.

Comment: A try/catch will not slow down your app (much) if no exception is thrown. You could check with regex to see if the "SomeText" looks like a point, but this will also take time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest, and probably cleanest way to achieve this is by implementing your own `TryParse` method for `Point.Parse`:

```
    public bool TryParse(string source, out Point point)
    {
        try
        {
            point = Point.Parse(source);
        }
        catch (FormatException ex)
        {
            point = default(Point);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Which you can then consume like so:

```
        Point point;
        if (!TryParse("12, 13", out point))
        {
            // We have an invalid Point!
        }
```

If your string isn't a valid point, the method will return false and you can do whatever needs to be done right away. The `out` parameter will contain the parsed `Point` if the parse succeeded, and will otherwise contain the default value for `Point`, which is probably (0, 0).

Do note that the exception is being supressed here, but that shouldn't give you any trouble. If need be, you can re-throw it after setting `point`.

Comment: Thanks @aevitas i used your method as an extension method

Answer (score 1):

If you actually read the documentation, you'll see an exception is thrown by `Point.Parse()` in three situations:

- source is not composed of two comma- or space-delimited double values.
- source does not contain two numbers.
- source contains too many delimiters.

So you'll have to either:

- Make sure your input represents a point and you don't pass bogus information to the method. We don't know where your input comes from, so that's up to you.
- Validate your input, for example using a regular expression. This may harm performance more than not validating, but that depends on the input and how often the input actually doesn't represent a point.
- Parse each string yourself, for example using `string.IndexOf()` and `string.Substring()` (or `RegEx.Match()`) and `double.TryParse()`, but then you're basically rebuilding `Point.Parse()` and can better return a `new Point { X = parsedX, Y = parsedY }` anyway.

Comment: promise i will read the doc twice next time before posting @CodeCaster Some times i'm stumbling for ideas and good practises